# How to create Routes for multiple Layouts in React?

Tags: reactjs, layout, frontend

I'm learning React. I'm trying to make Routes for my differents pages with different Layouts however it does not work. It does not show any error, just the blank page.
How can I make these different routes for different layouts?

I'm expecting to show every page with its corresponding layout.

```js
function App() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Routes>
                <Route path={['/admin']}>
                    <PrivateLayout>
                        <Routes>
                            <Route path='/admin' element={<Admin />} />
                        </Routes>
                    </PrivateLayout>
                </Route>
                <Route path={['/login', '/registro']}>
                    <AuthLayout>
                        <Routes>
                            <Route path='/login' element={<Login />} />
                            <Route path='/registro' element={<Registro />} />
                        </Routes>
                    </AuthLayout>
                </Route>
                <Route path={['/']}>
                    <PublicLayout>
                        <Routes>
                            <Route path='/' element={<Index />} />                            
                        </Routes>
                    </PublicLayout>
                </Route>
            </Routes>            
        </Router>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Take a look at this, https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-router-nested-routes/. Maybe it will clear up some doubts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
//import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route
      path="/admin"
      element={
        <PrivateLayout>
          <Outlet />
        </PrivateLayout>
      }
    >
      <Route path="/admin/" element={<Admin />} />
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</Router>


//PrivateLayout.js
const layout = ({ children }) => {
   return <div>
      ...
      { children }
      ...
   </div>;
};

export default layout;
```